# Importing file attached to post after DB migration in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file, migration

I migrated a DB off an old php website into my new wordpress DB.All work great except the attached file.
In the old DB i had a post_image table linked with the name off the image but i don't know how to import image for each post automatically ? Is this possible ?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tool like https://github.com/deliciousbrains/wp-migrate-db to migrate the wordpress db you don't have deal with this problem.

Comment: But the first website if not build with wordpress